# Conversion from std::wstring to LPBYTE

Tags: c++

I have a MS VC++ program without the MFC support. (That's why std::wstring instead of CString is used.)
I'm streaming data into a richedit using this method:

```
DWORD __stdcall MEditStreamInCallback(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    std::wstring *wsBuffer = (std::wstring *)dwCookie;
    cb = wsBuffer->length();

    for (int i = 0; i < cb; i++)
        *(pbBuff+i) = wsBuffer->c_str()[i];

    *pcb = cb;
    return 0;
}
```

It somehow works but I don't like the manual way of converting characters using a *for* loop.
Is there any function to perform this conversion in a more effective way?

Comment: Your loop looks fine. Just be sure to understand that you are not changing the encoding - you just copy the string as a byte-array.
You could also write `(LPBYTE pbBuff =  (LPBYTE)&wsBuffer[0];`

Comment: I'm copying wide char string to a byte array. So the typecast above won't work. )-:

Comment: You could use `WideCharToMultiByte` and actually properly convert wide string to the appropriate encoding.

Comment: There's hardly any API that's multibyte-only. For the last 20 years or so, UTF-16 has been the norm in Microsoft Windows. I strongly suspect you could just use the Unicode version and ignore all that character conversion nonsense.

Comment: @NotAnAdmin You are sort of right ;-)
Yet after the typecast, you got a pointer to your `wsBuffer`, just as a `LPBYTE`. You can copy that using any means you like. `wsBuffer.size()` gives you the length in 2-byte units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `WideCharToMultiByte`.

```
DWORD __stdcall MEditStreamInCallback(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    std::wstring *wsBuffer = (std::wstring *) dwCookie;    
    *pcb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wsBuffer->c_str(), wsBuffer->length(), pbBuff, cb, "?", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

You can fine-tune the conversion parameters as you please.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. It works. Just pbBuff must be typecast like (LPSTR)pbBuff and you have a typo "1c_str() - if you want to correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must populate the buffer pbBuff and there is not choise than copying the string, so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cb; i++)
    *(pbBuff+i) = wsBuffer->c_str()[i];

*pcb = cb;
```

is equivalent to

```
cb = min(cb, wsBuffer->length());
CopyMemory(pbBuff, &wsBuffer[0], cb * sizeof(wchar_t));
*pcb = cb;
```

btw, using `DWORD` to store a pointer works only with 32-bit Windows, have in mind that.

Comment: Thanks, but no. First, small fix to your solution: min(cb, wsBuffer->length());. Second it does not do the conversion - there is a rubbish in pbBuff after it. Finally, I'm using 64bit Windows. You meant that it only works with a 32bit compile of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited my answer. Can you explain why it didn't work?

Comment: It just copies the memory. It does not perform conversion from two byte char to single byte char.